# Remote Method Invocation

Tags: glassfish, ejb, remote-access

I have a session bean which implements a remote java interface.

Whenever a make a new remote method in interface and access it for the first time to access its session bean implemented method it throws an Error:

```
javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   
vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe
```

However when I re-deploy my application the error vanishes and it only happens for the very first time I access the remoted method of session bean.

My server is `GlassFish 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Happens if one tries to incrementally deploy the app on GlassFish server.
However, if the application is freshly deployed these errors won't come.